# Ant fails on Slave Jenkins on Mac

Tags: macos, ant, jenkins

I am getting this error:-

Cannot run program "ant" (in directory "/Users/test/~/.jenkins/~/.jenkins/workspace/"): error=2, No such file or directory.

As you can see that directory path is somehow messed up. I dont have idea where to fix it. I am new to jenkins so plz try to be descriptive.

I have slave jenkins in mac under user:- test/.jenkins

Comment: In the slave configuration screen, did you declare the Ant installation?

Comment: in Slave configuration screen, I have only added Tool Location of Ant as: 

Name  : Ant, 
Home  : /usr/local/bin/ant

Comment: But my first problem is that messed up directory path. Please help me out where m going wrong.

Comment: It was just to check your Ant installation (which seems correct). The problem is with your Jenkins home variable. When you click on the system information menu (on your slave), what is the value for the HOME variable (in the Environment variables section)?

Comment: hey bruno, it says /Users/test

Comment: but under the same section PWD = /Users/test/~/.jenkins

, which seems wrong i guess, it should be /Users/test/.jenkins....

Comment: If you go in the configure menu of your slave, what is the value for "Remote FS root"? I think it contains a wrong value :)

Comment: it has value ~/.jenkins

Comment: Can you try to change it to "/Users/test/.jenkins"?

Comment: I changed but still the problem persist. Do i need to restart my slave or anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81157/discussion-between-bruno-lavit-and-deepak).